# Move animation (Translate animation)

Tags: android, animation, button, move

I have a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNl"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/splashBtnOrange"
        android:layout_marginRight="5.50dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNoLanguage"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/splashBtnWhite"
        android:layout_marginRight="5.50dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFr"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/splashBtnGreen" />
```

And code like this :

```
    void HandleBtnNlClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        controller.SaveSetting("language","nl");

        TranslateAnimation anim2 = new TranslateAnimation(0,-((int)(btnFr.GetX() - btnNoLanguage.GetX())), 0, 0);
        anim2.Duration = 1000;
        anim2.FillAfter = true;

        TranslateAnimation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, btnNoLanguage.GetX()-btnNl.GetX(), 0, 0);
        anim1.Duration = 1000;
        anim1.FillAfter = true;

        btnNl.StartAnimation (anim1);
        btnFr.StartAnimation (anim2);



        //_initModel.gotoNextScreen ();
    }

    void HandleBtnFrClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        controller.SaveSetting("language","fr");

        TranslateAnimation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, btnNoLanguage.GetX()-btnNl.GetX(), 0, 0);
        anim1.Duration = 1000;
        anim1.FillAfter = true;

        TranslateAnimation anim2 = new TranslateAnimation(0,-((int)(btnFr.GetX() - btnNoLanguage.GetX())), 0, 0);
        anim2.Duration = 1000;
        anim2.FillAfter = true;

        btnNl.StartAnimation (anim1);
        btnFr.StartAnimation (anim2);
    }
```

When the btnFr gets pushed, btnFr and BtnNl have to move to the middle
(where the noLanguageBtn is).

Everything works fine the only problem is that when BtnFr gets pushed, 
it has to move on top of BtnNl. When BtnNl gets pushed, it has to move on top of BtnFr. How can i do this? at the moment btnFr always goes on top of BtnNl
because it's defined later in the layout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this at the end of the animation
BtnNl.bringToFront()

EDIT
Try this:
In the first portion of code when BTN1 click, instead of

```
btnNl.StartAnimation (anim1);
btnFr.StartAnimation (anim2);
```

flip the order like this

```
btnFr.StartAnimation (anim2);
btnNl.StartAnimation (anim1);
```

Comment: what do you mean it does not work?BtnNi still at at the back? Thats weird because bringToFront brings the view to be the top view. You have to implement animation listener and do it in OnAnimationEnd

Comment: it has to move over the other button, not spawn when the animation is done

Comment: I tried that also, without a good result. The problem is fixed. The whole layout was looking chaotic after bringtofront because of the linearlayout. i changed it to relativelayout and the problem was fixed, I used the same method as your edited answer :)